# Automatically sort music files into folders by album/artist names

Tags: mp3, music

I have a large collection of music files (let's say MP3), with metadata ([ID3 tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)), but all are located in the same folder. I wish to automatically organize all of them according to this metadata.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I suggest using [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/); it has a rich feature set and allows this quite simply. To do this with **Mp3tag**, simply:

1. Open it.
2. Select all the files you want to rename (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to change to a certain directory).
3. Select them all in the list (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
4. Go to the **Convert** menu at the top and select the first option, **Tag - Filename**.
5. For the format string, use my (in)famous one: `%artist%\%album%\%title%`
6. Click **OK** and watch the magic happen! It's truly a great program.

I hope this guide helped you and anyone else who is puzzled when it comes to organizing their music themselves without the aid of mainstream software like iTunes. Sometimes, I've found, you have to take things into *your own hands*!

#### Additional Info

Sometimes **Mp3tag** can become confused when working across multiple drives. To avoid this, include a path before the aforementioned format string (e.g., `D:\Users\Me\Desktop\%artist%\%album%\%title%`).

Comment: Much more intuitive than Picard. Insanely nice; thanks.

Comment: +1.  i LOVE mp3tag, and have been using it for years, and googled this question and..surprise surprise! it does this too.  It is truly an amazing program.

Comment: I suggest the simple format string `%artist% - %album%\%title%`. Other scripting functions like brackets, which display contents only if available, can be used.

Comment: How can I make Mp3tag monitor/scan and apply the properties to the files in the folder? I don't manually clicking "Save" every time I add a new song to the folder

Comment: This worked great!! Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardTagger).  It can be configured to move files into a hierarchy based on their metadata. It can also use the MusicBrainz database to correct your metadata...if you want it to.

Of course, you could also do this with a single command on a unix system.  I doubt that's what you want though.

Comment: Worked for me with the OS X version.

Comment: I have a synology diskstation, and a unix-y command that I could cron to do this would be enormously helpful.. Any chance you'd like to share?

Comment: It isn't obvious from reading the documentation how to accomplish this.  Can you be a bit more specific about how to use Picard to move files into a hierarchy based on metadata?

Comment: @Michael : It is: Options -> Options ->File Naming-> Rename files when saving... If you want to completely break previous folder structure you need to select Move files to this directory...

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) It allows you to specify a pattern based on the metadata you have, and use it for moving the files to the corresponding directories (creating each directory if needed). It can also use Amazon to find any missing metadata

Answer (score 2):

Give [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) a try.

iTunes sorts its media library in

artist
 album
   track 1
     .
     .
   track n