# How to use audiofingerprint sw (which?) to organise music by artist alphabetically, then artist then album/single/ep title?

Tags: audio, music, fingerprint, file-organization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically sort music files into folders by album/artist names](https://superuser.com/questions/171052/automatically-sort-music-files-into-folders-by-album-artist-names)

Some audio files from my CD collection don't have any meta data/name or are incomplete. I'd like to use audiofingerprinting to 1) recognise them 2) organise them.

I would like them organised in folders as follows

- Alphabetically by Artist first initial letter

  - Artist name

    - Album Title

      - track.mp3
      - track.mp3

    etc

Can I configure/automate/script audiofingerprinting software to do this?

Which software can do this? e.g. MusicBrainz Picard? (and how) I think WinAmp also does audiofingerprinting, so could this also be configured/automated/scripted?

I just want to be able to point the software, i.e. specify a folder location of the unordered untitled music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used MusicBrainz Picard very successfully for fingerprinting and fixing tags.  This quick start guide should get you up and running.

http://musicbrainz.org/doc/How_To_Tag_Files_With_Picard

Once you've got your tags sorted, you can move them around easy enough using something like [EasyTag](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1 @Colin Pickard. This looks straightforward (hopefully) just drag the unknown files to another place for it to do its recognition.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use musicbrainz for working out what the music is, and do the re-ordering with [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) - use 'convert tag to filename" and wildcards to do the naming - something like c:/foo/%artist%/%album% ....